# how to write SQL in EXCEL VBA with intelligence prompt

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Please advice me how to input SQL statement in EXCEL VBA with intelligence prompt? for example, when i write select statement, system can auto prompt table field after i write  a dot，just like i do it in sql server.

Comment: as far as I know, no such feature exist in EXCEL VBA. I would suggest you complete the SQL in SQL Server's environment then copy into VBA.

Comment: SQL is a very basic and logical language to write, I suggest you take the time to master your SQL skills as that would be more valuable in the long run.